# Permission dialog for "Modify System Settings"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-permissions

Application requires the following permissions

1- Camera

2- Allow modify system settings

User easily allow and deny the camera permission via permission dialog.

User gets confused on "Allow modify system settings" because instead of a permission dialog a screen is appeared (Image Attached Below).

[image]

Many of my App users are complaining that they get confused where to go after this permission screen is appeared. Is there any way to put a permission dialog instead or place a button that guides the user where to go next.

P.S. Ofcourse an acknowledged user knows that pressing a back button will get him out of it.

Comment: "Is there any way to put a permission dialog" -- no. "or place a button that guides the user where to go next" -- not easily, as that is not your UI. You could look into creating a floating window (the "Facebook chat heads" pattern) from a service. However, getting this right will be complicated, as you do not necessarily know when to get rid of that window.

Comment: IIRC, giving permission for an overlay app (e.g. to make a floating window) is the same complicated process, because it allows spying on the user's other apps. The reason Android did this is so that users could not install a virus, unless they were tech savvy enough to assess the risks themselves.